# How to generalize custom font path in one place so that next time while adding new font we change only at one place

Tags: android, xml, layout, custom-font

I am using below method to have a custom font. Now whenever i have to replace it with other font i have to change path everywhere in code. Is there any way to generalize path in one place ? Using it in string.xml won't work.

```
Typeface buttonfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/omnesreg.ttf");
button.setTypeface(buttonfont);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define a `public static final String FONT_PATH = "fonts/omnesreg.ttf";` somewhere and use it elsewhere?

Comment: Again this i will have to change in every class...Any more generic way where i just have to make changes in one file and it would reflect everywhere. As the "fonts/omnesreg.ttf" i cannot put in R.string.fontname

Answer (score 1):

Add a helper class to your project, e.g., `Utils.java` and define the font path as a public variable

Utils.java:

```
public static final String FONT_OMNESREG = "fonts/omnesreg.ttf";
```

Then elsewhere in your project, reference it from Utils.java. For example, in MainActivity.java you'd reference it as follows:

```
Typeface buttonfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), Utils.FONT_OMNESREG);
```

> Using it in string.xml won't work.

You can as well define it in `res/values/strings.xml`

```
<string name="font_path_omnesreg">fonts/omnesreg.ttf</string>
```

And use as follows:

```
Typeface buttonfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), getString(R.string.font_path_omnesreg));
```

Hope this helps.